# User scores Object and App scores Object

Tags: facebook-graph-api, aggregate

With the new Scores and Achievements roll-outs I have the following questions

1. Is there a difference between the **user's scores object** and the
   **app's scores object for the user**?
2. Does setting one affect the other?
3. In setting a scores object is it overwritten or aggregated?

There was a statement made in the docs about "games limited to 1000 points per game" for scores...does game refer to

1. The App in total?
2. the game per person?
3. the per person per game play e.g. (per turn/ per try/ per round)?

I ask this because I am developing a game where a user would have 2 sets of scoring and I want them to be counted both separately and as an aggregate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been playing around with scores and achievements and this is what I found out:

1. scores and achievements are separate.
2. Changing the score doesn't affect the achievements.
3. Adding achievements don't affect the score.
4. Scores don't aggregate, so if you assign a score to a user, the user will have the new score assigned.
5. Consider the achievements more like bonus points a user gets when doing a task. If you want to add the bonus points to a user's score, you'll have to assign a new score to the user.
6. I noticed that the updates in score or acheivements appear mainly when the page reloads.

7.When creating achievements, don't use an https link for the image else it won't be added.

8) The total points for achievements should not be greater than 1000pts but scores can go higher (how high I do not know).

I strongly suggest creating the achievements first in a test app and adding them to your app when you're sure about what you want. 
Hope I was able to help.